# foursquare:venues/search?intent=browse returns more places when specifying categoryIds one by one than without categoryId

Tags: api, search, foursquare

I use the *venues/search* endpoint of Foursquare to fetch **all** places around a point, within a given radius.

For example, if I query **without specifying any categoryId**:

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=48.857091635218225,2.341747995157864&radius=200&v=20151023&intent=browse

I get 11 places. If I additionally **specify a categoryId** (Food):

https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=48.857091635218225,2.341747995157864&radius=200&v=20151023&intent=browse&categoryId=4d4b7105d754a06374d81259

I get 23 places, all strictly located within the required radius. How can you get more Food places than places of any category?

I've made more general checks, and this seems to be a general behaviour of the API.

Is this an expected behavior? Any way to have an exhaustive list of places without having to query category by category?